# Submit the value of a timer which is then use for JS function

Tags: javascript, html, timer

I am trying to enable the user to set the value of a timer and then to see the countdown timer displayed on the webpage.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<p>Timer:</p> 
<input type="text" name="timing" id="demoC" style="height:50px;" value="3">
<div id="answer">Your dish will be ready in <span id="time"></span> minutes!</div>
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit" value="Submit">
```

And here is my JS code:

```
  function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);
  
        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
  
        display.text(minutes + ":" + seconds);
  
        if (--timer < 0) {
            timer = 0;
            var html = "Your dish is ready!!";
            document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = html;
        }
    }, 1000);
  }
  
  jQuery(function ($) {
    var  myVar = 60 * document.getElementById('demoC').value,
        display = $('#time');
    startTimer(myVar, display);
  });
```

This code is working because in the HTML file, I hardcoded the value to 3 minutes directly.

But I would like to remove this `value="3"`and be able to set it up manually in the input field.
But when I am doing that, the timer is not displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should add the 'id'-attribute to the input element:

```
 <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
```

But just setting the function glitches out the timer if the user inputs multiple values, so you should change your code like this:

```js
    var clearIntervalId;
    function startTimer(duration, display) {
        var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
        clearIntervalId = setInterval(function () {
            minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
            seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);
    
            minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
            seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
    
            display.text(minutes + ":" + seconds);
    
            if (--timer < 0) {
                timer = 0;
                var html = "Your dish is ready!!";
                document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = html;
            }
        }, 1000);
  }
  
    $("#submit").click(function(){
            var  myVar = 60 * document.getElementById('demoC').value,
                display = $('#time');
            if (typeof clearIntervalId !== 'undefined') {
                clearInterval(clearIntervalId)
            }
            startTimer(myVar, display);
    });
```

**clearIntervalId** is used, so that the previous running setInterval()-function is getting cleared out everytime the user clicks the button, so that there won't be interfering changes in the current minutes + seconds.

Answer (score 0):

What do you need is a trigger for the startTimer function after event
and in your code the event is a button click

Add id attribute to your button

```
 <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="submit" value="Submit">
```

and add click event listener to your button

```
 $("#submit").on("click",function(){
        var  myVar = 60 * document.getElementById('demoC').value,
            display = $('#time');
        startTimer(myVar, display);
    })
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, unfortunately it is not working either. When I click on the button `submit`, nothing happens. Moreover, I have a `status_code = 304` for my JS which there is no modification..
And when I try to add again the `value="3"` it is not working either, the timer is not displayed

Answer (score -1):

```js
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $("#submit").on("click",function(){
            var  myVar = 60 * document.getElementById('demoC').value,
                display = $('#time');
            startTimer(myVar, display);
        })
    });

    function startTimer(duration, display) {
        var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
        setInterval(function () {
            minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
            seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

            minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
            seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

            display.text(minutes + ":" + seconds);

            if (--timer < 0) {
                timer = 0;
                var html = "Your dish is ready!!";
                document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = html;
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <p>Timer:</p>
    <input type="text" name="timing" id="demoC" style="height:50px;" value="3">
    <div id="answer">Your dish will be ready in <span id="time"></span> minutes!</div>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="submit" value="Submit">
```